# Is there a Python function that finds all k-length orderings of a list?

Tags: python, combinations, permutation

I don't believe this precise question has been asked before. I was recently faced with a problem where I had to find just such a set. An example would probably help:-

Given some list:

```
list1 = ['a', 'b']
```

Is there a function that returns the following set?

```
output = {('a', 'b'), ('a', 'a'), ('b', 'b'), ('b', 'a')}
```

I have been able to generate the desired output using the `itertools`  `combinations_with_replacement` and `permutations` functions, as follows:

```
from itertools import combinations_with_replacement, permutations
set1 = set(combinations_with_replacement(['a', 'b'], 2))
set2 = set(permutations(['a', 'b'], 2))

>>> set1
{('a', 'b'), ('a', 'a'), ('b', 'b')}
>>> set2
{('b', 'a'), ('a', 'b')}

set1.update(set2)

>>> set1
{('a', 'b'), ('a', 'a'), ('b', 'b'), ('b', 'a')}
```

Is there a name for such a set? Is there an alternative method I can use?

Comment: Isn't `set1` the set you requested?

Comment: @Filip No, because it's _combinations_. So `(a, b)` and `(b, a)` are the same. But the fact that replacements are allowed means you can at least generate `(a, a)` and `(b, b)`.

Comment: If a (standard) function existed I would expect it to reside in `itertools`, as you've already explored - but maybe someone will shed light.

Comment: Am I missing something? You wanted this `output = {('a', 'b'), ('a', 'a'), ('b', 'b'), ('b', 'a')}` and you got this `{('a', 'b'), ('a', 'a'), ('b', 'b'), ('b', 'a')}` Where is the problem

Comment: @Filip I was trying to find an alternate method for computing the output set, as I discovered from L3viathan's answer, itertools.product() is the best way to compute the product set!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You want `itertools.product`:

```
>>> import itertools
>>> set(itertools.product(list1, repeat=2))
{('a', 'b'), ('b', 'a'), ('b', 'b'), ('a', 'a')}
```

`itertools.product` with the `repeat` parameter is essentially "`permutations_with_replacement`", which seems to be what you want.

Answer (score 2):

Itertools.product() does what you want:

```
mylist = ['a', 'b']
list(itertools.product(mylist, repeat=2))

Out[8]: [('a', 'a'), ('a', 'b'), ('b', 'a'), ('b', 'b')]
```